# What this php stack trace error means?

Tags: php, actionscript, stack-trace

```
[05-Mar-2012 02:38:58] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/pokerwor/public_html/request.php:275
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pokerwor/public_html/request.php(275): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
#1 /home/pokerwor/public_html/request.php(295): readXML()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/pokerwor/public_html/request.php on line 275
```

I have a flash file that sends a xml string to php in an interval.
sometimes my php file make this error ,any body knows what is this?

Comment: it means that what the flash sent is not valid xml.

Comment: Why sometimes it happens? probability = 1/100 ?

Comment: try catching the exception and logging the xml you've received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML string isn't valid XML. You should `var_dump()` the XML output to see what's wrong with the input. If you want to handle this error to have friendlier output, you can use a [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) construction:

```
try {
    // Load the XML
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

In the `catch` code you can also add debugging code, such as writing the XML contents to a log file. This way you won't have to reproduce the rare situation by ramming your refresh button a hundred times.

Comment: Please tell me more about this? catch , just runs if an error happens?

Comment: @AMINGholibeigian Yes, the code inside the `catch` block will only run if an exception is thrown by anything inside the `try` block. Also note that if an exception is encountered, the rest if the `try` block will be skipped; execution will leap straight to the `catch`.

Comment: is there any easy code sample to writing the XML contents to a log file?

Comment: @AMINGholibeigian The easiest would be `file_put_contents('somedebugfile.xml', $xmlstring);`. Try searching for it next time, you'll easily find how to perform simple tasks like writing to a file ;)